# Enable two-way data binding for form fields saved in a Vuex store in Nuxt.js

Tags: vue-component, vuex, nuxt.js

For mapping form fields to the Vuex store using two-way data binding with `v-model`, without directly modifying the store itself, but using getter and setter functions internally, it can be achieved as it is described in the official Vuex documentation: [Two-way Computed Property](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/forms.html#two-way-computed-property)), but I want to mutate the form instead of each field at a time. Is there any way I can achieve that? Any help would be appreciated.

this is the `form object` in my store

```
export const state = () => ({
  form: {
    name: null,
    phone_number: null,
    email: null
  }
})
```

how to achieve two way data binding for this form object between the component and the vuex store using mutations.

Comment: What means is "mutate the form instead of each field at a time"?

Comment: @pea3nut, here the form in the sense, it is an object with multiple properties like `name, email, phone_number`, as I said, vuex only supports to mutate only one value at a time. But, I want to mutate the form object instead of one field at a time.